# RPN Calculator for C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a code for an RPN Calculator, I am struggling with making it calculate correctly more than one "left" and "right" operand.

So far my code works for inputs such as:
10 15 + =                   25

I am having trouble figuring out how to get these inputs to output correctly:

Input: 100 10 50 25 / * - -2 / =        Output: -40

Also, right now I am just dividing the stack size by 2 which works for some of the error checking, but then it prints an error for something like the above/below input.
100 10 50 25 / * - -2 / =   -40

How do I get the code to error check for these two inputs below?

Input:  10 20 * / =                   Output:  Error: Too many operators

```
    12 20 30 / =                   Error: Too many operand
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <sstream> //make use of a class called istringstream
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

//Function prototype for isOperator
bool isOperator(const string& input);

//Function prototype for perforOperation
int performOperation(const string& input, stack<double>& calcStack);

int main()
{

    cout << "RPN Calculator: " << endl;
    cout << "Input\n";

    stack<double> calcStack;
    string input;


        while(input != "0")
        {
            //Terminate program when 0 is entered by user
            while(input != "=")
            {

            // get input
            cin >> input;

            // check for being numeric value
            double num;

                if(istringstream(input) >> num)
                {
                    //use push function
                    calcStack.push(num);
                }

                // check for operator
                else if(isOperator(input))
                {
                    performOperation(input, calcStack);
                }

                // If user enters 0 on a line followed by a new line, the program exits     ????????????
                else if(input == "0\n")
                {
                    return -1;
                }

                // invalid output check
                //else
                //{
                    //cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
                //}
            }
            }
}

    bool isOperator(const string& input)
    {
        string operators[] = {"-", "+", "*", "/"};

        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            if(input == operators[i])
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
}


int performOperation(const string& input, stack<double>& calcStack)
{
    double firstOperand;
    double secondOperand;
    double result;

    if( calcStack.size() > 2 )                      //Error check gives a false error for last input ???
    {
        cout << "Error: too many operands" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    //Error chceck for too many operators           ////STILL PRINT OUTPUT???
    if( calcStack.size() < 2 )
        {
            cout << "Error: too many operators" << endl;
            return 1;
        }


    secondOperand = calcStack.top();
    calcStack.pop();


    firstOperand = calcStack.top();
    calcStack.pop();


    if(input == "-")
    {
        result = firstOperand-secondOperand;
    }

    else if (input == "+")
    {
        result = firstOperand + secondOperand;
    }

    else if (input == "*")
    {
        result = firstOperand * secondOperand;
    }

    else if( input == "/")
    {
    result = firstOperand / secondOperand;
    }


    // If user enters 0 on a line followed by a new line, the program exits         ???????????
    else if(input == "0\n")
    {
    return -1;
    }

        //Division by zero error
        if(secondOperand == 0)
            {
                cout << "Error: Division by 0.\n";
                return -1;
            }

    cout << "Output\n";
    cout << result << endl;
    calcStack.push(result);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: This is a job for the debugger, man! Current problem is `if( calcStack.size() > 2 )` which it will be. There are only too many operands right at the end if you have more than one after all of the operators are done.

Comment: Tweak: isOperator can be reduced to a search for a character in a string. Something along the lines of `static const string operators ="-+*/"; if (input.length() == 1) return operators.find_first_of(input[0]) != string::npos; return false;`

Comment: You could research what other people have done with this assignment.  Search StackOverflow for "c++ rpn calculator".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bit of code here

```
if( calcStack.size() > 2 )                      
{
    cout << "Error: too many operands" << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Needs to move to main and slightly transform

```
else if(isOperator(input))
{
    performOperation(input, calcStack);
}
else if(input == "=")
{
    if (calcStack.size() != 1)
    {
        cout << "Error: too many operands" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Result: " << calcStack.top();
        // now decide whether or not you are preserving the result for
        // the next computation
        calcStack.pop(); // Assuming not keeping result
    }
}
```

And that means you'll need to rethink this loop `while(input != "=")`

You're really close.

Two suggestions:

You can optimize the isOperator function.

```
bool isOperator(const string& input)
{
    static const string operators ="-+*/";
    if (input.length() == 1) // right size to be an operator.
    {
        return operators.find_first_of(input[0]) != string::npos;
        // look in the operator string for the first (and only) character in input
    }
    return false;
}
```

And since you know there is only one character in the operator, you can use something more elegant than if/else if:

```
switch (input[0])
{
    case '-':
        result = firstOperand - secondOperand;
        break;
    case '+':
        result = firstOperand + secondOperand;
        break;
    case '*':
        result = firstOperand * secondOperand;
        break;
    case '/':
        if (secondOperand == 0)
        { // moved this test to here because it's the only place it matters.
            cout << "Error: Division by 0.\n";
            return -1;
        }
        result = firstOperand / secondOperand;
        break;
}
```

## addendum to deal with comment

By this point your code should have changed quite a bit and you might want to start a new question with your current code. If not, this is what I'm talking about in the comments.

```
else if(isOperator(input))
{
    if (performOperation(input, calcStack) != 0)
    {
        // empty out the stack and delete all pending user input.
        calcStack.clear(); 
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
        cout << "Bad input. Try again." << endl;
        break; // exit input loop.
     }
}
else if(input == "=")
{
...
```

Comment: How can I make this part of the code function without still printing the output? :     
  if( calcStack.size() < 2 )
   {
    cout << "Error: too many operators" << endl;
    return 1;
    
   }                                                                                                                                                                                           I have tried using a while loop and break statement, which works but causes a run time error. If I move this bit of code to main, It gives an error for this input: 100 10 50 25 / * - -2 / =

Comment: You would have to read the return value of `performOperation` in main and determine from the return value that the input is bad. After that it's up to you whether you want to let the user try again, or stop processing the input and start a new computation.

Comment: That is not entirely clear to me, I have tried so many things, I think I may just keep it simple at this point and use an exit(0); instead of a return. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: @Audrey updated answer. Recommend making a new question with your current code to deal with the current bug properly. It's best to deal with one problem per question because it keeps the answers concise and easier to use for future people with the same or similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
double helpRpnFunc(string arr[], int& size) {
    if (size == 0)
        throw "Error: Too many operators\n";
    try {
        return stoi(arr[size - 1]);
    }
    catch (invalid_argument) {
        char operator1 = arr[size - 1][0];
        double secondOperand = helpRpnFunc(arr, --size), firstOperand = helpRpnFunc(arr, --size);
        switch (operator1) {
        case '+':
            return firstOperand + secondOperand;
        case '-':
            return firstOperand - secondOperand;
        case '*':
            return firstOperand * secondOperand;
        case '/':`enter code here`
            if (secondOperand == 0)
                throw "Error: canot divide by 0!\n";
            return firstOperand / secondOperand;
        }
    }
}
string rpnFunc(string arr[], int size) {
    try {
        string str = to_string(helpRpnFunc(arr, size));
        if (size > 1)
            throw "Error: too many operands";
        return str.substr(0, str.find(".") + 3);
    }
    catch (const char* error) {
        return error;
    }
}
int main()
{
    string arr1[] = { "100","10","50","25","/","*","-","-2","/" };
    int size = 9;
    cout << rpnFunc(arr1, size) << endl;
    string arr2[] = { "10","20","*","/" };
    size = 4;
    cout << rpnFunc(arr2, size) << endl;
    string arr3[] = { "12","20","30","/" };
    cout << rpnFunc(arr3, size) << endl;
}
```